# Converting java xml sax event calls to an xml string

Tags: java, xml, serialization, deserialization, sax

Does java xml sax api provide a `ContentHandler` subclass which would convert the event calls to an xml string. For example, the following calls to this handler should produce the following `xml`:

```
XMLPrinterHandler h;
String data = "hello";
h.startDocument();
h.startElement("", "element", "element", new Attributes());
h.characters(h.toCharArray(), 0, h.size());
h.endElement("", "element", "element");
h.endDocument();
System.out.println(h.getXml());
```

This should print:

```
<element>hello</element>
```

I'm dealing with some code which encodes some data as `xml` and would like to know the intermediate output. The encoding class takes a `ContentHandler` and calls the appropriate methods on it to encode the data.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
SAXTransformerFactory f = new SAXTransformerFactory();
TransformerHandler t = new f.newTransformerHandler();
t.setResult(System.out);
t.startDocument();
etc
```

The `TransformerHandler` performs a "null transformation" from SAX input to lexical XML output.

You can also use

```
h.getTransformer().setOutputProperty()
```

to set serialization properties such as indenting, based on the properties defined in the XSLT specification. (The standard JDK `TransformerHandler` gives you XSLT 1.0 serialization properties, if you want the extended set defined in XSLT 3.0 plus Saxon extensions, use the Saxon implementation.)

Personally I find that writing Java code as a direct client of the SAX `ContentHandler` interface is very clumsy. I much prefer the `XMLStreamWriter` interface.